# The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again. Magento2. Flat rate. Stuck at checkout

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

Im stuck at checkout/#shipping with The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again.

I've configured the flat rate shipping method and its not showing up in the page.

Image reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable the `Free shipping` from Admin for the testing purpose. And check the checkout page, If Free shipping is showing , it means shipping methods working.
2. Check the `flat rate` configuration in Admin like store the website, Enable, any country specified, state and post-code.

Please check the configuration carefully and any third party module related checkout, disable it. And clear all cache.

Comment: 1. Tried enabling only free shipping. 

Getting this error "The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again."

2.  flat rate enabled to all allowed countries.

Still issue persist. 
No third party plugins used.

Comment: please check log from magento_root/var/log/